# Почему не срабатывает код добавления записи в PostgreSQL?

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

Я использую PostgreSQL версии 9.5, Qt  и пытаюсь добавить запись в таблицу, но у меня не срабатывает следующий код :

```
void MainWindow::SaveFiles()
{
    Login conn;
    conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery* queryAddNote = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

    QString newDir = QString(QDir::currentPath()+"/Наблюдение_%1").arg(QString(QDate::currentDate().toString()).replace(" ","_"));
    QDir().mkdir(newDir);
    Progress->show();
    Progress->setMinimum(0);
    for (int i=1;i<model->rowCount();i++) {
        Progress->setMaximum(model->rowCount()-1);
        if (model->index(i,0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toBool()==true) {
            QFile::copy(model->index(i,1).data().toString(),newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
            QString sqlQueryAddNote = QString("INSERT INTO public.\"DataObservationLog\" (data,path_data) VALUES (\"%1\",\"%2\")")
                    .arg(QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName())
                    .arg(newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
            qDebug()<<sqlQueryAddNote;
            queryAddNote->prepare(sqlQueryAddNote);
            //queryAddNote->prepare("INSERT INTO DataObservationLog (data,path_data)" "VALUES (:data,:path_data)");
            //queryAddNote->bindValue(":data", QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
            //queryAddNote->bindValue(":path_data", newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
            qDebug()<<queryAddNote->lastError();
            queryAddNote->exec();
            Progress->setValue(i);
        } else {

        }
    }
    conn.connClose();
    Progress->hide();
    TableDisk->setModel(nullptr);
}
```

Причём пробовал и так :

```
    queryAddNote->prepare("INSERT INTO DataObservationLog (data,path_data)" "VALUES (:data,:path_data)");
    queryAddNote->bindValue(":data", QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
    queryAddNote->bindValue(":path_data", newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
    qDebug()<<queryAddNote->lastError();
    queryAddNote->exec();
```

И так :

```
QString sqlQueryAddNote = QString("INSERT INTO DataObservationLog (data,path_data) VALUES ('%1','%2')")
                        .arg(QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName())
                        .arg(newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(model->index(i,1).data().toString()).fileName());
```

К базе подключается без ошибок и подключаюсь я так :

login.h

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H
#include <QtSql>
#include <QMessageBox>

class Login
{
  public:
    Login();
    QSqlDatabase mydb;
    void connClose()
    {
        mydb.close();
        mydb.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
    }


    bool connOpen()
    {
        mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
        mydb.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        mydb.setDatabaseName("ObservationLog");
        mydb.setUserName("postgres");
        mydb.setPassword("123456789");
        if(!mydb.open()) {
            qDebug()<<("Не удачная попытка открыть базу");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<("База подключена...");
            return true;
        }
    }
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в название таблицы . По видимо называть таблицы должно быть в нижнем регистре "dataobservationlog".

Comment: Да, PostgreSQL учитывает регистр букв в названии. Крайне рекомендую скачать отсюда документацию и постоянно ее курить: https://postgrespro.ru/docs (внизу страницы - правая колонка). Еще обратите внимание: плагины PostgreSQL очень своеобразно относятся к возвращаемым результатам в части ошибок сервера. Это было причиной отказа мной от использования встроенных плагинов и написания собственной обвязки API. У меня такой бы ситуации просто не возникло - сервер всегда возвращает ошибки и я бы ее увидел. Ну, типа "table not found...".